# Making a button to show a toast and sending a data to another activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

I am trying to send data from one activity to another and also to show toast when the button is pressed I am trying to accomplish both at same time.The id of the button I have assigned is `add_to_cart` and I tried this code below and i didnt work

```
Button customToastButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.add_to_cart);
    customToastButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            //get the LayoutInflater and inflate the custom_toast layout
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cart_toast, (ViewGroup)
                    findViewById(R.id.toast_layout_root));

            //get the TextView from the custom_toast layout
            TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.toastText);
            text.setText("Item as been added to cart");

            //create the toast object, set display duration,
            //set the view as layout that's inflated above and then call show()
            Toast t = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
            t.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            t.setView(layout);
            t.show();


            Bundle intent = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (intent != null) {
                firstname= intent.getString("Gladwin");
                secondname= intent.getString("james");
            }



        }

    });
```

The toast part works fine but not the data sending part and I tried Implementing  separately this code to send the data but was not responsive and below is the code I am using to receive the data sent

```
private String firstname;
private String secondname;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);


    TextView txtFirst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    txtFirst.setText(firstname);
    TextView txtSecond=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txtSecond.setText(secondname);
```

and this is the XML part of the receiving end

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<TextView
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:id="@+id/textview1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

I know there a are lot of newbie mistakes sorry for that tho

Comment: have you opened the activity that receives the intent before passing the intent too?

Comment: Yes I could only if I throw up the code like this
 'public void add_to_cart(View view){
             Intent nextIntent = new Intent(this, cart.class);
            startActivity(nextIntent);
        }'

Comment: ok, it´s possible that the activity is still opened and can´t get the intent. If so, either you have to finish this receiving activity if you leaving it or other way is to override the protected method onNewIntent() and catch it there. But then you have to set the attribute `singleTop` in your manifest to that activity.

Comment: I am newbie I cant understand what you are saying can you please be little clear or edit the code

Comment: ok, so you said that the receiving activity, let´s call it ActivityB, was opened before. Now for example by pressing back button, you are leaving that activity. But it is still alive in the system. What you should do here is, Override onBackPressed() and call finish() inside to finish this activity. Then, if you start it again, the intent should be passed everytime...

Comment: yes ,I tried it too it didn't work I am going to upload the final code I have.If you have time now or later or when ever you please have look into it

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I have uploaded the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let´s assume you have opened the `Activity` that should receive the `intent` before. The problem here is, that if you leaving this `activity` and does not `finish` it, it´s still alive as long as the system needs not much resources. So, then you are going to the next `activity` where you send the intent and start th receiving `activity` again. But here is the trick: the `activity` just comes back to screen, but had never died. So the `intent` is not received. Do it this way

**Sending the `intent`:**

```
 public class SendingActivity extends Activity {

     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){ 

          @Override
          public void onClick(View v){

          Intent testIntent = new Intent(SendingActivity.this, ReceivingActivity.class);
          testIntent.putExtra("firstname","Eggsy");
          testIntent.putExtra("lastname","Iggsy");
          startActivity(testIntent);
        }
    });
   }
```

**Receiving `intent` in the `activity` and `finish` after leaving:**

```
    public class ReceivingActivity extends Activity {

//make TextView objects
private TextView txtFirst;
private TextView txtSecond;

       @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.your_activty_xml);

      //initialize textViews <-- this has to be done with all views
      txtFirst = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourFirstTextViewId);
      txtSecond = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yourSecondTextViewId);


      Intent intent = getIntent();
      String firstName = intent.getStringExtra("firstname");
      if(firstName!=null){
      txtFirst.setText(firstName);
      }
      String lastName = intent.getStringExtra("lastname");
      if(lastName!=null){
      txtSecond.setText(lastName);
      }

      }

       @Override
         onBackPressed(){    
         finish();
         super.onBackPressed();   
         }         
    }
```

From updated question, I think you have a general problem with understanding the order of `activities lifecycle`. `OnCreate()` will be called on start of `activity` and the `views` are set. The `String variables` that you set to the `textView` will not changed automatically, you´ll have to do it in your `button click method`. So, above example should be added to your `onClick` if you don´t want to do it at the start directly:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v){

 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String firstName = intent.getStringExtra("firstname");
 if(firstName!=null){
    txtFirst.setText(firstName);
  }

 String lastName = intent.getStringExtra("lastname");
 if(lastName!=null){
    txtSecond.setText(lastName);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hope you wont mind if I ask why txtFirst and txtSecond is high lighten and say's cannot resolve symbol

Comment: You have to create the Objects in your Activity, see my edit in the ReceiveActivity. This textViews you have to refer with the id´s of your layout xml. Like you´ll have to do it with all your views in your layout.xml

Comment: Thank you so much I learnt so much from you in one day and I highly appreciate your patience and supported you gace me all this time. Thanks once again

Comment: you´re welcome, I also had get much support here in SO. It´s part of giving and taking :)

Comment: Is it possible  to send the datas with out starting the activity I tried by removing the startActivity(testIntent); 
but still didnt work, anything you can help me through..???

Comment: there are different possibilities, it depends on what your goal is. To pass a few informations between activities, this is the best way. But to access big data on information, storing in a database will be better. For example, if you want to make a list with details about food, ListView and SQLite Database is an example. On the other way, if you just want to save small amount of data, sharedPreferences are also a good approach.

Comment: My favorite "teacher" is google, you´ll find everything here if you know how to do a correct search. Besides google, the examples from Mkyong and javacodegeeks helped me a lot in the past. See here: http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/database/android-database-example/

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Answer (score 1):

To get data from other activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(currentactivity.this, targetactivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("XXX", value);
```

You need a String value, in this case: text and a string name in this case: uid

Then to get the uid in another activity:

```
String uid = getIntent().getExtras().getString("XXX");
```

Comment: @Eggsy because this is my code. let me edit the code. its edited, you have to change XXX into whatever you want and then value is the value you want to cross over to the other activity.

Answer (score 0):

In data receiving side Do like this....

```
    private String firstname;
    private String secondname;
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                firstname= bundle.getString("firstname");
                secondname= bundle.getString("Secondname");
            }

    TextView txtFirst=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
    txtFirst.setText(firstname);
    TextView txtSecond=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    txtSecond.setText(secondname);
```

Comment: @Eggsy It is the more secure way to check the bundle before assigning the values to the String...

Comment: How to call the above in second activity will the code I have provided will be enough..????

Comment: Now i got printed like this "firstname" "secondname" it didnt actually fetch the actual name

Comment: @Eggsy Code is right...So, you have to debug your application or apply Log on it